# RemoveClass not responding to two part form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, css

I have a form that I am controlling visually with jQuery. I am using removeClass to remove a few classes on the first part of the form, which works fine. However when the button is clicked to go to the second part of the form, the form is not responding to the removeClass and I can't figure out why this is happening. I have tried adding an event (below) to see if I am able to target the class/id within the div, but no luck either. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('input#createMember').click(function(){
      $.find('account-edit-engagement-block').removeClass('col-md-6');
  });
});
```

Ok Here is the code for the form. I am trying to remove the classes associated to this segment ""

---

```
<div class="form-container promo-carousel-lp__form">
   <h4>Get $150 for signing up</h4>

   <div class="account-edit-engagement-block"><script
   src="/bundles/ActivationFormBlock?
    v=FmZitrV3y_UtI4ysqjWZ2dKUPIGjPegx-dWRIDqgcrI1"></script>


    <div id="activateAccount">
    <div class="">
        <div id="activationview"></div>
        <div id="editview">
        <script src="/bundles/AccountEdit?
        v=V6iouLyL7iEfMRGYC4DTKQc8Yv95VNfdF_08-ZAgeRU1"></script>


    <div id="editAccount">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
        <form action="/api/UserApi/EditUserAsync"
```

Comment: You might need to add the code for the form too.

Comment: It's going to be difficult to help without actually seeing your code. From what you have above, the only thing I can tell you is that `$.find()` is going to look for an element with a tag name of `account-edit-engagement-block` which I'm guessing isn't what you meant. Probably need `.` or `#` in front of that.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u5bLfrks/1/ This finds the elements that are contained inside the element with class "account_edit_engagement-block" who has the class "col-md-6" and remove the class.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT Try this again, iterate:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('input#createMember').click(function(){        
      $('.account-edit-engagement-block').each(function(ix,ex){
         $(ex).find('.col-md-6').removeClass('col-md-6');
      });
   });
});
```

Fiddle HERE: https://jsfiddle.net/u5bLfrks/1/

Comment: `$.find()` is invalid method

Comment: Yes, sorry I did forget to add the "." in the first example.

Comment: But it still does not target the class I am trying to control.